# Pyspark Join Tables

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new in Pyspark. I have 'Table A' and 'Table B' and I need join both to get 'Table C'. Can anyone help-me please?

I'm using DataFrames...

I don't know how to join that tables all together in the right way...

**Table A**:

```
+--+----------+-----+    
|id|year_month| qt  |
+--+----------+-----+
| 1|   2015-05| 190 |
| 2|   2015-06| 390 |
+--+----------+-----+
```

**Table B**:

```
+---------+-----+
year_month| sem |
+---------+-----+
|  2016-01| 1   |
|  2015-02| 1   |
|  2015-03| 1   |
|  2016-04| 1   |
|  2015-05| 1   |
|  2015-06| 1   |
|  2016-07| 2   |
|  2015-08| 2   |
|  2015-09| 2   |
|  2016-10| 2   |
|  2015-11| 2   |
|  2015-12| 2   |
+---------+-----+
```

**Table C**:
The join add columns and also add rows...

```
+--+----------+-----+-----+    
|id|year_month| qt  | sem |
+--+----------+-----+-----+
| 1| 2015-05  | 0   | 1   | 
| 1| 2016-01  | 0   | 1   |
| 1| 2015-02  | 0   | 1   |
| 1| 2015-03  | 0   | 1   |
| 1| 2016-04  | 0   | 1   |
| 1| 2015-05  | 190 | 1   |
| 1| 2015-06  | 0   | 1   | 
| 1| 2016-07  | 0   | 2   |
| 1| 2015-08  | 0   | 2   |
| 1| 2015-09  | 0   | 2   |
| 1| 2016-10  | 0   | 2   |
| 1| 2015-11  | 0   | 2   |
| 1| 2015-12  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2015-05  | 0   | 1   | 
| 2| 2016-01  | 0   | 1   |
| 2| 2015-02  | 0   | 1   |
| 2| 2015-03  | 0   | 1   |
| 2| 2016-04  | 0   | 1   |
| 2| 2015-05  | 0   | 1   |
| 2| 2015-06  | 390 | 1   | 
| 2| 2016-07  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2015-08  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2015-09  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2016-10  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2015-11  | 0   | 2   |
| 2| 2015-12  | 0   | 2   |
+--+----------+-----+-----+
```

**Code**:

```
from pyspark import HiveContext
sqlContext =  HiveContext(sc)

lA = [(1,"2015-05",190),(2,"2015-06",390)]
tableA = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lA, ["id","year_month","qt"])
tableA.show()

lB = [("2016-01",1),("2015-02",1),("2015-03",1),("2016-04",1),
      ("2015-05",1),("2015-06",1),("2016-07",2),("2015-08",2),
      ("2015-09",2),("2016-10",2),("2015-11",2),("2015-12",2)]
tableB = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lB,["year_month","sem"])
tableB.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a `join` more a cartesian product (`cross join`)

**Spark 2**

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
tableA.crossJoin(tableB)\
    .withColumn(
        "qt", 
        psf.when(tableB.year_month == tableA.year_month, psf.col("qt")).otherwise(0))\
    .drop(tableA.year_month)
```

**Spark 1.6**

```py
tableA.join(tableB)\
    .withColumn(
        "qt", 
        psf.when(tableB.year_month == tableA.year_month, psf.col("qt")).otherwise(0))\
    .drop(tableA.year_month)

+---+---+----------+---+
| id| qt|year_month|sem|
+---+---+----------+---+
|  1|  0|   2015-02|  1|
|  1|  0|   2015-03|  1|
|  1|190|   2015-05|  1|
|  1|  0|   2015-06|  1|
|  1|  0|   2016-01|  1|
|  1|  0|   2016-04|  1|
|  1|  0|   2015-08|  2|
|  1|  0|   2015-09|  2|
|  1|  0|   2015-11|  2|
|  1|  0|   2015-12|  2|
|  1|  0|   2016-07|  2|
|  1|  0|   2016-10|  2|
|  2|  0|   2015-02|  1|
|  2|  0|   2015-03|  1|
|  2|  0|   2015-05|  1|
|  2|390|   2015-06|  1|
|  2|  0|   2016-01|  1|
|  2|  0|   2016-04|  1|
|  2|  0|   2015-08|  2|
|  2|  0|   2015-09|  2|
|  2|  0|   2015-11|  2|
|  2|  0|   2015-12|  2|
|  2|  0|   2016-07|  2|
|  2|  0|   2016-10|  2|
+---+---+----------+---+
```